# Can the Chinese EV BYD E6 charge at Tesla charging station?

Tags: electrical, battery, charging

I am just wondering, are there any customers of this exotic brand, especially in the US?

And btw can any other EV (e.g. Nissan Leaf, Toyota RAV4 EV) charge at Tesla's fast charging stations?

Comment: While I don't know the answer, the question is completely appropriate from my point of view.

Comment: We will need to get some and on BYD sales/imports in the US, which I presume are really low number. For the charging station, I do not have a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as of right now is **no**.  The BYD e6 EV can only be charged by a BYD charging station. If you look at these plugs, you'll see the difference between the two:

Standard J1772 plug

[image]

BYD e6 plug

[image]

In [this cars.com article](http://blogs.cars.com/kickingtires/2012/07/coming-to-america-the-chinese-byd-e6-.html) the author talks about charging the e6:

> The The Chinese-spec model can be charged by a powerful 100-kilowatt charging cabinet, outputting 360 volts DC and an AC output current of 300 amps, which can charge the big battery completely in less than 40 minutes, according to BYD. The only issue with the charger is it's a Chinese standard that's not used in the U.S.; Snower has to charge the model at a BYD charging cabinet he installed in his brother-in-law's house. He told me that BYD is working on putting SAE-compliant charging options on the e6.

NOTE: In the article, "Snower" is the person in the US who owns the e6 the guy is talking about.

You can also go to the [BYD website](http://www.byd.com/na/) and see what they have to offer.

Answer (score 0):

The BYD can charge at every public charging point, excerpt CHADEMO ,Combo
And superchargers, The last one is for Tesla only.... the plug in the picture is the DC plug, But the car has also a AC connection

Update: here in Europe it can charge at 
Public type 2 mode 3 chargers (doesn't have the name mode 3 in US)
In US it maybe charge on AC in a different
Way than overhere. (Via adapter)

Comment: Do you have any links or references? This could be a great update to the answer I posted a year or so ago.